# Rest API call in angular 4 getting CORS error

Tags: angular

Rest API call in angular 4 getting CORS error
Failed to load "API url": No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

please help me how to fix using code only.

Comment: CORS is a server side error, talk to your backend developer or change your backend code.

Comment: What server side language are you using?

Comment: I am using php framework Codeigniter.